# Google Cloud disk multiple snapshot schedules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

Is it possible to have multiple snapshot schedules assigned to a single disk in Google Cloud Compute Engine?

My goal is to have a daily snapshot schedule with a certain retention policy and a weekly snapshot schedule with a different retention policy, both for the same disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Cloud supports only one "attached" snapshot schedule for persistent disks.

[Creating scheduled snapshots for persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124498679) open for this already. Keep in mind that there are no ETAs for Feature Request. But as mentioned above, “A persistent disk can have only one snapshot schedule attached to it at a time.”